# Map alphabetic sequence to integer

Tags: ruby, mapping

I want to implement an alphabetic code which maps to an integer.

For example:

```
A = 1
B = 2
C = 3
...
Z = 26
AA = 27
AB = 28
...
BA = 53
...
ZZ = 702
```

What the best way to do this mapping so that I can easily convert from an alphabetic code into a number and vice versa?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: There are several ways to do this, and which one is best depends on the mapping scheme you need (which numbers become which letter sequences). Do you have a specific mapping in mind - is your example exactly what you are looking for? Either way, please explain, ideally using Ruby code, in what way you are stuck - what prevents you doing this yourself?

Comment: The specific mapping I have in mind is specified in my question. My example is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
('A'..'ZZ').to_a[694] # "ZS"
('A'..'ZZ').to_a.index("ZS") # 694
```

Ruby array indexing starts at 0. If you really want it to start at 1 you can do:

```
('A'..'ZZ').to_a.unshift(nil)[694] # "ZR"
('A'..'ZZ').to_a.unshift(nil).index("ZR") # 694
```

Comment: Brilliant! thanks. really appreciate the constructive response.

Comment: I think you should note this approach has limitations - it uses a fair amount of memory/CPU, depending on the maximum number that needs converting. Assuming that's OK (and I think it must be for OP), it could be made more efficient by caching `('A'..'ZZ').to_a.unshift(nil)` in a variable for re-use.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it like this.

```
str_num_map = lambda do |val|
    arr = ('A'..'ZZ').to_a
    val.is_a?(String) ? (arr.index(val) + 1) : (arr[val-1])
  end

str_num_map.call(1) # => 'A'
str_num_map.call('ZZ') # => 702
```